# git resume rebase using reflog

Tags: git, git-rebase

I aborted in the middle of a long interactive rebase process since a conflict resolution went terribly wrong.

I notice that the reflog has refs to each time a rebase was `git rebase --continue`d.

How can I resume rebasing from the last successful `--continue` point such that the previous conflict resolutions from the rebase are kept?  (If I were to run the rebase command again from scratch, I would have to manually resolve all the conflicts that I already resolved the first time I went through it)

Example:

Suppose an interactive rebase went as follows (where 000002 was resolved successfully and 0000004 was such an utter disaster that the rebase was aborted)

```
edit 000001 Edit to this commit
pick 000002 Easy merge conflict, resolved
pick 000003 Commit 3
pick 000004 Really ugly merge conflict, Abort!
pick 000005 Commit 5
```

The reflog now looks like this

```
HEAD@{0}: rebase: aborting
HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (pick): updating HEAD
HEAD@{2}: rebase -i (pick): updating HEAD
HEAD@{3}: rebase -i (edit): updating HEAD
HEAD@{4}: rebase -i (start): checkout 000000
```

What I want to do is `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` and continue the original rebase process, giving "Really ugly merge conflict" another try (and continuing to pick 000005).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase does not have anything built in to do this, and it's a bit tricky to do it "right", but there's an easy way to do it "wrong" by creating a *new* branch pointing to the part of the rebase you liked:

```
$ git branch newbr HEAD@{1}
```

Now you can check out branch `newbr` and use `git cherry-pick` to start in on the ugly-merge-conflict version.  The downside is that you must manually `git cherry-pick` the set of commits you want to bring in (in this case, 4 and 5).

(Once you have everything cherry-picked in to the new branch, just re-point the original branch to your new final commit—that's the tip of your new branch—just as `git rebase` would have on success.  You can then delete the new branch since your manual-mode rebase is complete.)

Comment: Supposing that past 000005 there is a lot of history (or future?) which is quite complex (including merge commits from other branches and such).  Is there no easier way than replaying the entire `git cherry-pick` and `git merge` sequence?

Comment: Using a similar approach, if I'm still early in the rebase, would it be easier to create a new branch and run the same rebase command again, using `git checkout` to resolve the merges along the way?  Would that create any weird histories pointing to the orphaned rebase refs?

Comment: @arcyqwerty: an interactive rebase *is* a series of cherry-picks.  That's why the word in the directives is "pick".  Rebasing normally deletes merges; interactive rebase allows you to preserve them, but the method by which it does it is full of hairy corner cases.  See the rebase script, e.g., `vim $(git --exec-path)/git-rebase--interactive`.  The "wrong" method above works because we create a new branch whose tip is the last commit you made just before abandoning the rebase effort, i.e., we're just sticking a label onto the anonymous branch-so-far.